# Subversive plugin not installing on kepler

Tags: svn

When i want to download subversive plugin for eclipse kepler, it was not downloaded and problem occurred installing the software. I tried so many times, but it would give same error. i.e

> ..An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/2.0/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.help_2.0.4.I20150123-1700.jar.
>   Read timed out Unable to read repository at
>   http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/2.0/update-site/plugins/org.eclipse.team.svn.sources_2.0.4.I20150123-1700.jar.
>   Connection reset.

Answer (score 0):

You have some connectivity issue. These URLs work for me. [Here is the instruction about installing Subversive.](https://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for giving some  important information.Finally SVN plugin and connector installed in my system properly.